# Insert a contact form from an app into a Class view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

If you have this view

```
class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

where index.html have this structure

```
{% block content %}
    {% include "content.html" %}
{% content %}
```

How do you include this view from a contact app inside content.html?

```
def contactForm(request):
    #....some form processing here
return render(request, "contact.html", {'form': form})
```

So inside content.html you have a contact form when submit is a success it just stays on content.html saying success.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the `get_context_data` in `index` view. Like this:

```
class index(TemplateView):  # please use CamelCase when naming classes
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
       context = super(index, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
       context['form'] = ContactForm()
       return context
```

Comment: By the way how do you refresh the contact form without reloading the whole page like using ajax?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FromView, they are designed to display and validate a basic form.
You can create some custom logic on form_valid or form invalid.
If the default behavior is ok don't use them.

For the success message have a look to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

class Index(SuccessMessageMixin,FormView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = ContactForm()
    #name of your index view defined in urls.py
    success_url = reverse_lazy('name_of_your_index_view')
    success_message = "Success"


    #OPTIONAL:if you want some custom logic if the form is valid
    def form_valid(self, form):
        #custom logic here
        return super(Index,self).form_valid(form)

    #OPTIONAL:for custom logic if the form is invalid
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        #custom logic here
        return super(Index,self).form_invalid(form)
```

In the html don't forget to put something like:

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: how about Templateview which is used by other templates?

Comment: The TemplateView is design to render a template. You can make it work the same way, but at the end you will endup creating a pseudo FormView. Also FormView manage the form validation out of the box and the TemplateView solution doesn't.
So if your Form is processed by another django view, using TemplateView is a better approach. But if you need to manage the displaying and the validation of the form in the same view then use FormView. Add check out https://ccbv.co.uk/ it helps a lot to understand class based view.

Comment: By the way how do you refresh the contact form without reloading the whole page like using ajax?